# Does CentOS 6.4 Support UEFI and SECURE BOOT Fully?

Tags: linux, windows-8, uefi, centos-6, secure-boot

Does Minimal Edition of CentOS 6.4 support UEFI & SECURE BOOT fully?
I want to install it besides Windows 8. Now does it install normally or does it not support UEFI & SECURE BOOT fully yet?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK RHEL 6 has basic support for UEFI (grub-efi, efibootmgr) with no support for Secure Boot. This means you have to turn off Secure Boot on Windows 8 logo machines if you want to install CentOS 6. I'm not aware of multiboot support for RHEL UEFI installation.

Disclaimer: I did UEFI QA at Red Hat. This does not represent the official stance of Red Hat.

Comment: Thanks, For your reply. I want multi boot between Windows8 and CentOS6.4. I guess i have to test it!

Comment: *As of CentOS 7 you no longer have to disable secure boot.*

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to disable Secure Boot on computers that bear a Windows 8 logo, although the details of how to do this are not standardized. You can then install any Linux distribution that supports EFI (assuming no hardware incompatibilities, serious bugs, etc.). If you like, you can then install the shim or PreBootloader program, adjust the boot path, and re-enable Secure Boot. Once you know what you're doing, this isn't very hard; but the learning curve is significant. See [my page on the topic](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html) for details, which are far too extensive to include here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, If CentOS 6.4 support UEFI and Multi boot i will install it! because i want to boot my win8 from Grub.